# Google testing of composite classes in C++

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have below piece of code written:

```
//Source code sample

//Class A is the class under test
class A{
public:
  A(){
    B *b = new B;
  }
  void func1()
  {
    b->func2();
  }
};

class B
{
  void func2()
  {
    //here a function from third class is called.
  }
};

//Test case
class MockB : public B
{
  MOCK_METHOD0(func2(), void());
}

TEST_F(A, TC1_func1)
{
  MockB mock;
  A *a = new A;
  a->func1();
  EXPECT_CALL(mock, func2()).Times(1);
}
```

Here the body of func1 contains just a call to func2. I want to write a test case for func1.
My question is, how can we test whether the func2() is called or not from func1?

Note:

1. class A creates the instance of class B
2. I do not want to pass the pointer of class B as an argument to the constructor of class A
3. I do not want to make any changes to the source code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"I do not want to pass the pointer of class B as an argument to the constructor of class A"_ But that's literally the answer. It's how to compose types properly to permit good mocking and unit testing. Why don't you want to do it?

Comment: *"I do not want to make any changes to the source code."*. Sad as it doesn't compile: `b` is not a member, but a local variable.

Comment: All your `new` leak and might be avoided.

Comment: 1. I do not want to pass the pointer of class B as an argument to the constructor of class A. This is because, the code has gone much ahead in the development. Any changes in the source code at this point may lead to defects.

Comment: Updated TEST_F to make the code more clear. Object b is a member of class A and object mock is the member of TEST_F. In func1(), func2 is called on object b. But in TEST_F, how do I make sure that func2 is called successfully? Func2 neither takes any argument nor it returns any value.

Any suggestion/solution would be of great help.